# Jenkins Pipeline - using P4Publish with submit operation never ends

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, perforce, unreal-engine4

I'm a little bit stuck and Jenkins P4 plugin documentation is minimal at best.

I have a Jenkins Pipeline that do a P4publish + Submit operation as it last stage. But the problem is that the submit operation never ends, even after many hours waiting. The changelist is accessible in p4v and can be submitted without errors, but the jenkins task will never ends.

Any ideas?

here is the pipeline code (generated from jenkins pipeline syntax helper):

echo "Publishing Stable Engine..."

p4publish credential: 'illogika', publish: submit(
delete: false,
description: 'Submitted by Jenkins. Build: ${BUILD_TAG}',
modtime: false,
onlyOnSuccess: false,
paths: '', purge: '',
reopen: false),
workspace: manualSpec(
charset: 'none',
cleanup: false,
name: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-publish',
pinHost: false,
spec: clientSpec(
allwrite: true,
backup: true,
changeView: '',
clobber: true,
compress: false,
line: 'LOCAL',
locked: false,
modtime: false,
rmdir: false,
serverID: '',
streamName: '',
type: 'WRITABLE',
view: '''//ep1tome/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/... //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-publish/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/...
-//ep1tome/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/.../*.pdb //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-publish/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/.../*.pdb
-//ep1tome/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Programs/AutomationTool/Saved/... //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-publish/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Programs/AutomationTool/Saved/...
//ep1tome/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Binaries/.../*.pdb //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-publish/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Binaries/.../*.pdb
//ep1tome/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Intermediate/Build/BuildRules/*.pdb //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-publish/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Intermediate/Build/BuildRules/*.pdb
//ep1tome/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Source/Programs/.../*.pdb //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-publish/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Source/Programs/.../*.pdb
//ep1tome/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Platforms/.../*.pdb //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-publish/AQPPipeline/UE4-AQP/Engine/Platforms/.../*.pdb'''))

[jenkins logs capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfqAE.png)

Thanks

Comment: It can be hard to troubleshoot a submit that appears 'hung' in the p4 plugin.

If you change the publish to shelve instead, does that complete?

When run in P4V, how long does it take to submit? Approximately how many files and size?  Is P4V using parallel submit?

As a test and if you have a lot of files, can you change your publish clientSpec's view to be narrower so that only a few small files would be submitted?
The p4 plugin uses a different API compared to P4V and that might be a problem for Support.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get around this problem by creating many smaller submits and keeping around 5k-7k files per submit. (not sure if its the amount of files or the size)